# Firefox 29+ UI components disappear in private browsing

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I created a Firefox extension that consists of a [`ui/toolbar`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_toolbar) from Firefox's newest Addon SDK. I gave the extension [permission for private browsing in the package.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/private-browsing) of the extension.

When I set Firefox to use "Permanent Private Browsing", the extension disappears.

Does any one know how to allow the new `ui` components to be used in private browsing mode from startup? Configurations to the browser and/or extension?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug, namely https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1026614

There are no viable work-around besides patching the SDK yourself. But I wouldn't recommend that if you want to host your add-on on [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/) ; add-ons using a modified SDK will be rejected.

Your best bet is waiting for the bug to get fixed.

Comment: I added that bug. Thanks nmaier for your help.

Comment: Heh. And now I diagnosed and confirmed it. Team work! *highfive*